# Locking Down Wordpress Application Password Permissions / Capabilities

Tags: user-roles, password, capabilities, third-party-applications

I am working on a Wordpress installation where we recently decoupled the frontend into a NextJS application that is no longer hosted on the same domain as the admin. We are accessing data etc through the API.

That's been fine for non-logged in users viewing posts etc. But recently we realized that the "preview post" functionality has been broken, because users who are logged in on the admin side are no longer logged in on the frontend. So they can't preview posts they're working on.

To preview posts via the WP API, you have to authenticate to it. It seemed like an Application Password was the best solution for this. However, I don't want to grant any permissions to the Application Password *except* the ability to preview posts (that's the `edit_others_posts` permission).

So I created a special role with *only* the `edit_others_posts` capability, and attached to Application Password to a user with that role.

Unfortunately I'm still able to do a lot more with it that I'd like. I can list users, for example - that's a capability that's usually reserved only for Admins and Super admins. I can see tags and taxonomies, I can create a post - but not delete it. I can't view / manage plugins or settings, or view the application passwords of the super admin user, so that's bit of a relief.

I just don't know how to get my hands around *what* this password allows and how to manage it securely. But [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oH4b1LnIVus) seems to suggest it's the preferred, secure way and has made things like JWT tokens obsolete.

I've seen conflicting information out there - [some blog posts saying](https://getshieldsecurity.com/blog/wordpress-application-passwords/) that an Application Password only has as many permissions as the user it's attached to. But then I see [the actual integration guide](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) (from when they moved this functionality from a plugin to core) says that authentication scoping is a future feature they'd love to implement.

Where can I find information on how Application Password permissions are determined? And do I have any control whatsoever over what permissions are granted via an Application Password? This has been incredibly frustrating. Any help is greatly appreciated!